# Check Toggle button state and manual trigger it using C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to trigger ToggleButton programmatically using C#.

I have a ToggleButton the switch imaged between muted and unmuted. If I toggle the button to muted I have the expected image but if I change the VolumeBar I have to trigger the button from C# because if doesn't do it automatically.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="MuteBtn" Height="20" Width="20" Background="Transparent" Click="MuteButton_Click">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>                                               
                    <Image Source="/Resources/audio-volume_on.ico" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="/Resources/volume_off.ico" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

I have a class called  VolumeBar_ValueChanged that has to Toggle the button based on the VolumeBar Value.

Comment: Why don't you try setting ToggleButton `IsChecked` property to true or false

Comment: MuteBtn.IsChecked = true/false should help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anu Viswan said, The isChecked property may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ControlTemplate for ToggleButton.

```
    <ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Image x:Name="borderImage" Source="Image1.jpg"/>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image2.jpg" TargetName="borderImage"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
```